# Json4s parse JSON string error

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I have the following piece of code:

```
def fromString[T <: AnyRef](str: String)(implicit m: Manifest[T]): T = {
    val json = parse(str)
    json.extract[T](formats,m)
}
```

I also have a case class that is defined as such:

```
case class Points(pts: Seq[Point])
case class Point(date: LocalDate, value: Double)
```

When I try to make the function call:

```
fromString[Points]
```

I get an error stating:

```
expected field or array
Near: \",\"value\":2.0}]}"
```

So normally this would imply that the JSON string is malformatted, but I confirmed that it is valid JSON. (see input string below)

```
"{\"pts\":[{\"date\":\"12-31-1969\",\"value\":1.0},{\"date\":\"01-31-1970\",\"value\":2.0}]}"
```

I have tried implementing a CustomSerializer and put it in scope of the implicit formats, but still no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the beginning and end quotes aren't being picked up as part of the JSON? "Expected field or array" means that its not picking up "pts": [...] and instead is just seeing a string.

Comment: You have a problem escaping the quotes. It is detecting `\"` instead of just `"`. Where do you get the json from?

Comment: Thank you, both for the suggestions. 

The problem ended up being as you described, by having the additional " around the entire string it did not get formatted correctly for deserialization. The JSON was created incorrectly because my CustomSerializer for it was just wrong. I deleted the CustomSerializer since this class only contains standard Scala-defined & serializable objects and it worked as expected.